# Blinking form windows in Qt5 application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a rather complex Qt application with a lot of different ui elements/files.
Basically, when going from a welcome screen to the main application view, I have a few small windows appearing and almost immediately disappearing. The only text on them is the window title "Form", like so.

[image: The unknown windows]

I assume this has something to do with some ui elements not having a parent, or something like that, but I have no idea what to look for exactly? I don't know where to look for either because there are no clue on the windows themselves and too many graphical elements to blindly go through each of them.

Any idea on to remove them, or at least a method to try to solve this would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

EDIT:
Most of the code looks like this:

```
myPanelQWidget = new MyPanel(this);
leftPanelQStackedWidgets->addWidget(myPanelQWidget);
leftPanelQStackedWidgets->setCurrentWidget(myPanelQWidget);
```

Comment: It would be great if you can post some code samples, specially when and where you defined/declared the widgets. You can always start the app in debug mode and check step by step where the unwanted forms are appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to widgets not having parents when they were created, but they quickly disappeared because they were then immediately added in a layout.